# Is there a way to programmatically create new users on Google Apps Email?

Tags: gmail

Is there any way to create a new user on Google Apps email, via some sort of API?

I need to create new users upon a specific trigger in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this:

http://code.google.com/googleapps/domain/gdata_provisioning_api_v2.0_developers_protocol.html